# Highcharts unable to handle large amount of data?

Tags: highcharts

I have a highcharts chart on jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hohenheim/j8cTE/15/

The graph does not render when the page loads but when I hover over the area where the chart should be, some bars render.

Here is what it looks like on my screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuUNr.png Is there a way to make the highcharts render on load and to render properly?

Note if you want to see if the data, you can uncomment the alert line.

```
//alert(JSON.stringify(data2));
```

Comment: Could you point me what is wrong, because when I run your example, colums are displayed without any problems (blue columns)

Comment: It's bug in 4.0.1 version, already fixed on our master branch, see: http://jsfiddle.net/j8cTE/18/ - patch will be included in 4.0.2 release.

Comment: @Sebastian see my imgur link to see what it looks like on my screen. I've noticed it working at different resolutions and its working for me now though.

Comment: @Pawl thanks - so as long as I use github.highcharts link and not code.highcharts - I should be okay?

Comment: I advice to download github version. It's master branch before tests, and some of commits may break your chart.

Comment: @Pawel Following up on this - I've noticed this is reoccuring even with the github link. This happens for when I use a smaller resolution but the issue is resolved with I switch to a larger screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: this is a known bug in 4.0.1 of highcharts as per Pawel's comment. Solution is to change up the highcharts references to working versions.